# only shows HOMEVIEW in air mobile flex app emulator flash builder

Tags: flash, flash-builder

i was running code of famous book pro-android flash.pdf . but it shows HOMEVIEW in top left postion air mobile flex app emulator in  flash builder nothing else ?

i successfully overlaid air sdk 21 with flex 4.6

Answer (score 0):

ok. i have got it . "HomeView" is the default blank flash builder project like "hello word " 
why it was happening ?
while importing a flex project you were creating another default blank flex project .

but how ?
File->New->Flex Mobile Project->
then you were giving different name for project name and project location
as a result two flex projects are created every time you are doing so .

so the project name  must be exactly same as project location folder name

i am not allowed to upload pic here as i have low score here . so to see the screenshot look here : http://graphicscoder.org/flex/only-shows-homeview-in-air-mobile-flex-app-emulator-flash-builder/